# How to enable a disabled input field?

Tags: javascript, html, input, tags, disabled-input

I want to know how to enable a disabled input field.

```
<input type="text" class="form" value="Text" disabled="">
```

I've tried to use this code via tampermonkey

```
var fContrl = document.getElementsByClassName("form");
for (var i = 0; i < fContrl.length; i++)
    fContrl[i].setAttribute("disabled", false);
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: A good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html

Comment: I am going to mark the question as duplicate.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna You can't. You need 3k rep for that. Also, no need to mention. :)

Comment: mark should be replaced by flagged, isn't it? @Ivar

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna You can flag it so it will end up in the review queue/a automated comment is placed, but it does not counts as a closing vote nor will your name appear after the "marked as duplicate by". [You will need 3k for that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: I know & understand, that's why I said mark should be replaced by flagged.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the property not the attribute

```
// Disable
fContrl[i].disabled = true;

// Enable
fContrl[i].disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

*remove* the *disabled* attribute - see demo below:

```js
var fContrl = document.getElementsByClassName("form");
for (var i = 0; i < fContrl.length; i++)
    fContrl[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form" value="Text" disabled="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var fContrl = document.getElementsByClassName("form");
for (var i = 0; i < fContrl.length; i++)
    fContrl[i].disabled=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp).

You can directly remove the attribute disabled.

```
fContrl[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove disable attribute from your input field.

**JavaScript Code**

```
fContrl[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by changing the line

```
 fContrl[i].setAttribute("disabled", false);
```

to

```
fContrl[i].disabled=false;
```